# sometimes selenium don't get inspection element

Tags: selenium

i'm trying to crawling this part
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXeQ4.png)

sometimes selenium got that part, but sometimes not.
But i don't figure out the reason why.

my code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:(my path)\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.rocketpunch.com/companies?page=1'

driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
html = driver.page_source
print(html)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
comments = soup.findAll('h4', {'class': 'header name'})


for comment in comments:
    print(comment)
```

Comment: page_source is likely not fetching what you want. It's a best attempt at capturing the page BEFORE many elements and data are loaded inot the DOM.

Comment: Use Explicit wait, it will wait till the element loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` you are using here just add some short fixed delay like `time.sleep(1)`
`implicitly_wait` waits until some element is found. It doesn't wait for all the elements / the entire page to be loaded.